# PHP-GD ownCloud issue

Tags: 14.04, apache2, php, owncloud-server

I'm trying  to set up my ownCloud for my school but there is just 1 problem

> PHP module GD not installed.
>
> ```
> Please ask your server administrator to install the module.
> PHP modules have been installed, but they are still listed as missing?
>
> Please ask your server administrator to restart the web server.
> ```

I have installed php5-gd like 4 times from different sources, restarted Apache every time, I have even reinstalled Ubuntu server in my machine (cause of the mess of installing and reinstalling stuff)

I'm new on this. I started Ubuntu like 1 month ago (love it) and trying to set up the server for 1 week ago actually.

I have to say I'm really annoyed cause of the php-gd cause I have fixed every "problem" I have gotten during the installation of other stuff but PHP gd beat me. All solutions I have found are related to installation, but I have the impression that maybe I'm missing something in Apache2. I don't feel like not installing ownCloud or change OS just cause ownCloud tells me "PHP module GD not installed."

I'm working on Ubuntu server 14.04 following this tutorial [How To install own cloud](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-owncloud-7-on-ubuntu-14.04) also tried with the ownCloud install instructions of the own cloud page, but have to say this:

> All downloads OK
>
> All updates OK
>
> Repository stuff No Errors all OK
>
> Tried with PHP 5 and PHP 7 modules
>
> Used Ubuntu server 16 before learning that 14.04 was better ( ironic)
>
> Apache running with no problems (access via XXX.XXX.X.X and I get
>   Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page)
>
> I have access to ownCloud ( on xxx.xxx.x.x/owncloud) just see the
>   errors

> Please update your question with the version of owncloud you're
>   trying, and also the error that's output from owncloud

I have tried with the ownCloud 7,8, and 9.0.2 (which is the actual stable version).
The only error I get is this screen: [ownCloud - GD module missing screeshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wd33d.png)

Comment: Please update your question with the version of owncloud you're trying, and also the error that's output from owncloud.

Comment: After installing the module, it may not be getting enabled. Try `sudo php5enmod gd` after installing it with `apt-get install php5-gd`. Don't forget to restart apache enabling the module.

Comment: THANKS  Dan thats was the fix,  now not willing to be annoying but   wut did i just did  with " en mod ?   By the way problem is fixed   im new so i don't know how to close  the thread and giving points

Answer (score 0):

Installing the `php5-gd` module with `apt-get install php5-gd` does not enable the module directly. In order to enable it, you should use the following command before restarting apache.

```
sudo php5enmod gd
sudo apache2ctl restart
```

---

`php5enmod` stands for **PHP5** **En**able **mod**ule. This the same command you can use for enabling Apache2 modules (`a2enmod`), but for PHP5 modules.
To disable modules you would use `php5dismod`.